# No backing field could be found for property and the property does not have a getter with value objects

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, value-objects

I have client class:

```
public class Client
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public ClientId ClientId { get; set; }
}
```

And value object (record) `ClientId`:

```
public record ClientId
{
    private ClientId() { }

    public ClientId(string clientId)
    {
        if (!CanCreate(clientId))
            throw new ArgumentException($"'{nameof(clientId)}' must be 32 bytes long Base64Url encoded string.");

        Value = clientId;
    }

    public string Value { get; private init; }

    public static bool CanCreate(string clientId)
    {
        return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(clientId) && Base64UrlEncoder.Validate(clientId, out int length) && length == 32;
    }
}
```

And when I want to find `Client` by `ClientId`:

```
public async Task<T?> FindByClientId<T>(ClientId clientId, Expression<Func<Client, T>> selector, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default,
    params Expression<Func<Client, object>>[] include)
{
    if (selector is null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(selector));

    var baseQuery = _dbContext.Clients.AsNoTrackingWithIdentityResolution()
        .Where(p => p.ClientId == clientId);
    
    return await include.Aggregate(baseQuery, (current, inc) => current.Include(inc))
        .Select(selector)
        .SingleOrDefaultAsync(cancellationToken);
}
```

I always get this error:

`System.InvalidOperationException: No backing field could be found for property 'ClientId.ClientId' and the property does not have a getter.`

This is my `Client` configuration:

```
public class ClientConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Client>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Client> builder)
    {
        builder.OwnsOne(p => p.ClientId, buildAction =>
        {
            buildAction.Property(p => p.Value)
            .HasColumnName(nameof(Client.ClientId))
            .HasMaxLength(43);

            buildAction.HasIndex(p => p.Value).IsUnique();
        });
    }
}
```

Why that's not working? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: In the constructor `ClientId(string clientId)`, try renaming `clientId` to `value`.

Comment: Still the same exception, should I do migration after this change?